# Remove leading blanks / spaces and empty lines in JSP File on compile

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I have a problem removing leading blanks / spaces and empty lines in a JSP file. To reduce the size of each jsp file, these useless blanks should be removed when I build my project.

Maven is used for building the project. Is there any possibility to remove this in all jsp files (e.g. with a regex)? I've not found any possibility so far.

The only thing I found was to remove directive whitespaces with `trimDirectiveWhitespaces` in the jsp file, but this doesn't removed the leading spaces.

For programming these formatting is needed to have a good overview, but it would be very nice if the compiler (or pre-compiler) could remove this in the `.war` file.

**An example:**

File:

```
<div class="half left">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name:</th>
                    <td>${person.firstname}&nbsp;${person.surname}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tel:</th>
                    <td>${person.phone}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Fax:</th>
                    <td>${person.fax}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>E-Mail:</th>
                    <td><a href="mailto:${person.email}">${person.email}</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>
```

File in `.war` after compiling:

```
<div class="half left">
<h2>Contact</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name:</th>
<td>${person.firstname}&nbsp;${person.surname}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Tel:</th>
<td>${person.phone}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Fax:</th>
<td>${person.fax}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>E-Mail:</th>
<td><a href="mailto:${person.email}">${person.email}</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

If anybody has an idea (maybe directly in the `pom.xml`?) thanks for a response.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have the idear but based on interest why one would possible do that (i am a backend developer that just learned something :)) i found this post:

http://blog.gkishor.net/2014/05/removing-white-space-in-jsps-for-webapps-using-maven/

A quick test on one of our components containing JSPs was successful.

Comment: Well, I've added it like in the blog-post, but it has the wrong syntax, because of the < and > symols in the token and replace values. But when I replace the signs with &lt; and &gt; it doesn't make any changes...For a test I've replaced every div with test, that worked, so the path is correct and the replacement works basically....Do you have an idea?

Comment: Sorry i dont know I just made made a quite similar small test with static words only rather than wildcards/ regex as shown in the blogpost. Maybe you can find further information (it seems to be a pretty common plugin so i dont expect it to have such "basic bugs" for example but i havent checked) via the plugin documentation https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

Comment: Well there really is a bugticket for exactly my problem...but that's not your fail, so I'll upvote the answer, because it works with normal replacements ;)

Comment: @MarcelBalzer Arg sorry to hear that :/ (i myself should have made that test..)

Comment: The link is dead.